# Ejecutar PHP sin recargar la página

Tags: php, android, ajax, post

Tengo una aplicación Android, la cual se conecta mediante HTTP con el ordenador (y mediante Apache), le envía unos datos mediante el método POST a un archivo PHP llamado `insert.php`, el cual se encarga de coger los datos recibidos e insertarlos en una base de datos MySQL.
Antes de que éste documento finalice o envíe la respuesta a Android, quiero que se ejecute otro archivo PHP llamado `sendMessage.php`, pasándole tres parámetros por el método POST, pero a su vez, no quiero que el primer PHP ténga que esperar a que finalice la ejecución del segundo para enviarle la respuesta a Android, ya que tarda varios segundos.
Actualmente lo tengo así, al final del primer documento tengo `include 'sendMessage.php'`, y las variables las tengo declaradas globales, pero ésto me produce el retraso mencionado (adjunto código):

```
    global $nombre;
    global $apellidos;
    global $email;
    include 'sendMessage.php';
```

He probado otras formas, con Ajax, o JQuery, he utilizado el método:

```
<script>
    $.post("sendMessage.php",{misdatoscon:POST}, function(){
        //A ejecutar al acabar la ejecución del fichero
    });
</script>
```

Esto último si me ha funcionado, pero, como lleva javascript, solo si ejecuto el fichero desde el ordenador, ya que el navegador lo interpreta, si lo hago desde mi aplicación Android, recibe como respuesta el código javascript, pero no lo ejecuta.

¿Existe alguna forma de ejecutar un archivo PHP desde otro, pero sin abrirlo, sin recargar la página o sin esperar respuesta de éste? A ser posible sin Ajax, o utilizar Ajax sin javascript, solo con PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ejecutar el fichero mediante consola con php, en cuyo caso, los parámetros tendrías que pasarlos como argumentos y no como variables `$_POST`

Para que la ejecución de php principal no espere a la finalización del subproceso, una función como esta podría ayudarte:

```
<?php
function execInBackground($cmd) 
{ 
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows") { 
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
    } else { 
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
    } 
}
```

La función está sacada de [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/function.exec.php#86329)

De esta manera:

```
 $cmd = 'php -f {rutaATuFicheroPHP} arg1 arg2 argX';
 execInBackground($cmd);
```

Sustituye `{rutaATuFicheroPHP}` por la ruta a tu fichero php y arg1 arg2 argX por los valores que quieras pasarle a la ejecución.

Ten en cuenta que tendrás que tener instalado php-CLI, y este debe estar en un directorio incluido en el PATH de tu sistema y con permisos de ejecución etc. Tienes más información sobre ello [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/features.commandline.php)

Para acceder desde un script ejecutado por consola CLI a los argumentos pasados puedes usar el array global [argv](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.argv.php).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [*cURL*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php):

```
<?php
//Crear un nuevo recurso cURL.
$ch = curl_init();

//Establecer la URL y otras opciones apropiadas.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.ejemplo.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

//Agarrar la URL y pasarla al navegador.
curl_exec($ch);

//Cerrar el recurso cURL y liberar recursos del sistema.
curl_close($ch);
?>
```